# How can I build a reset Button in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, reset

I'm currently learning how to access API data and have built an app using React that generates random Simpsons quotes.

I'd like to build a reset function that, in effect, reloads in the data from the API when a button is clicked, but I can't get this to work (I keep getting a 'can't access property "map"' error on reload).

I've tried lots of different permutations of the code but can't seem to get it right. Any ideas please?

````
import axios from 'axios'
import CharacterCard from './CharacterCard'

import './CharacterList.css'

const CharacterList = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCharactersFromApi() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes?count=100'
      )
      setCharacters(response.data)
    }
    getCharactersFromApi()
  }, [])

  const reset = () => {
    setCharacters('')
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='CharacterList'>
        {characters.map((character) => (
          <CharacterCard {...character} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={reset}>New Quotes?</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default CharacterList```
````

Comment: Original state was an array, so reset back to that, i.e. `setCharacters([])` instead of `setCharacters('')`. Strings don't have a `.map` property. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

in reset function, you making the characters a string so when you perform map on the empty string it will produce this error, so instead make it like `const reset = () => { setCharacters([]) }` to reset it as an array